# Can't Access LinkedIn Company Stats via API

Tags: linkedin-api

when trying to get this endpoint :     [https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/company-statistics](https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/%7Bid%7D/company-statistics)

we are getting the following error:

```
"Member 87483729 does not have permission to get company 123928234", status: 403..."
```

Their docs say :

"*All calls to Companies API endpoints will require the authenticated user to be flagged as an administrator of the LinkedIn Company Page that is the target of the API call.  You become the administrator of a page when you create it.  If the page already exists, you will have to contact the existing administrator to grant admin access to other LinkedIn members.*"

Funny thing is,  we do have admin rights to the page.

Answer (score 0):

We figured it out :

"I had to add permissions to the app, but as i was already logged in
and the auth was done by the cookie..i coudn't see the changes"

Comment: How did you add permissions to the app?  You just clicked the rw_admin box correct?  Ive done that and still not working for me